# Is the set of real algebraic numbers in $(0,1)$ the same as the set of fractional parts of real algebraic numbers in $(1, \infty )$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

It seems that way to me, but I'm not sure how to prove it rigorously.

Say, we have the number $x>1$ that is a root of some polynomial with integer coefficients:

$$a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+\dots +a_n x^n=0$$

Then if I separate the integer and fractional parts of the number, I get the equation:

$$a_0+a_1 (M+y)+a_2 (M+y)^2+\dots +a_n (M+y)^n=0$$

It's still an equation with integer coefficients for a variable $y<1$.

> But how do I prove that there are no algebraic numbers between $0$ and $1$ that don't serve as a fractional part of some other number(s) $x>1$?

Comment: $x$ is algebraic iff $x+n$ is algebraic for every integer $n$ (even for every algebraic number $n$). So an algebraic number in $]0,1[$ can't be a fractional part of a transcendental number.

Comment: Moreover, what are you calling "isomorphic" in this context? Are you just interested in equinumerosity?

Comment: @Watson, I mean 'the same'. I actually don't know anything about general algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ the set of algebraic numbers between $0$ and $1$ and let
$$B = \{\{x\} \mid x>1 \text{ algebraic }\}$$
where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Then $A=B$.

- $\subset$ : if $x \in A$, then $x = \{x+1\} \in B$, since $x+1>1$ is algebraic.
- $\supset$ : if $y = \{x\} \in B$ with $x>1$ algebraic then $x=N+y$ for some integer $N$, so that $y = x-N \in ]0,1[$ is algebraic (because the sum and the difference of algebraic numbers is [algebraic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314170/algebraic-numbers-are-a-field?rq=1)), i.e. $y \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Use the fact that for $n$ integer you have $x$ algebraic if and only if $x+n$ is algebraic.

This comes for free from the fact that the sum of two algebraic is algebraic.

As a consequence you get:

$x$ is algebraic if and only if the fractional part of $x$ is algebraic.